# Files to request from designer for developer?

Tags: photoshop, psd

I've got a question that pertains to mobile graphic design & app development.  I'll be using a graphic designer who will create the design, look and feel of the app.  Then I was told to request layered .psd files to then pass on to the developer.

My question is:  Are layered PSD files the only things that I need to request for the developer?

What other things should I consider?

Thank you all for your help...

Comment: When shopping for a graphic designer this is actually a _great_ question to ask candidates.  "What artifacts can you create that can be directly used in the project?"  I don't know much about mobile graphics, but for a web development project I'd be more inclined to choose a designer who can work with ASP.NET MVC Views than just in Photoshop.  Or at _least_ create HTML/CSS that I can use.  Ask the designers what artifacts they can give you that would be more directly useful to the project and reduce duplication of work.  Let them sell themselves to you.

Answer (score 0):

They are good enough. Layers make your design more configurable. When you buy a layered PSD image you can easily get/delete/move an object (i.e. button) from that PSD file. Say that you have a button and you want to move it somewhere, you need a picture of that button (i.e. picture layer of an button) and layered PSD file contains that picture layer that you can easily obtain. Everything else is based on do you like the design or not. *Simple as that.*